# Classifier vector of Naive Bayes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes, objective-function

I am trying to define a objective/loss function for the Naive Bayes classifier in Sklearn. However, the objective function has 'w' which is the classifier vector. This confuses me because I thought the Naive Bayes classifier only uses probabilities.
So my questions are,

Is it possible to define a objective/loss function for the Naive Bayes classifier? If possible how?

What would be the classifier vector 'w' in the Naive Bayes classifer?